# How can I change the value of all Labels in a loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, text, label

I'm trying to change the value of my label to some value located in an array. I have a loop that goes through my array

I want to be able to do something like this

Label & i.text = "some text"

```
Dim QuestionArray(10) As String
'dr is OleDbDataReader from database
While dr.Read()
QuestionArray(cnt)=(dr("Question").ToString)
cnt+=1
End While

For i = 0 To QuestionArray.Length
'Label(i) can not be used
Label(i).text = QuestionArray(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Show your code. Why do you want to map your labels to indices in an array? That's meaningless and very  error prone.

Comment: What would be the best way then? I'm not sure which part of my code would really help you to understand what I'm trying to do. Basically I take data from a database, put it into an array then I want the Labels text to be the same as in the database

Comment: @phil652 how are we supposed to know what the array actually is? If you can't provide what you are doing now, how are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Post your model array.. and code

Comment: Another question, what is the array defined as it can be many different things...

Comment: @TimSchmelter  I added some code now if you want to tell me how to proceed it might be easier now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array to hold your labels.

```
Dim LabelArray() As Label = {Label0, Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, _
  Label6, Label7, Label8, Label9, Label10}
    For i = 0 To QuestionArray.Length - 1
        LabelArray(i).Text = QuestionArray(i)
    Next
```

Comment: This works just had to change LabelArray(i) = QuestionArray(i) to LabelArray(i).text = QuestionArray(i). Thank you

Comment: @phil652 Thanks. I will correct the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i hope it helps you...

```
For Each objCtrl As Control In yourFormName.Controls
        ' Assign Some Text 
If TypeOf objCtrl Is Label Then
End If
Next
```

Comment: @Jaleelnazir        I don't want all the labels to have the same text. I have edit my question now if you want to look at my code you might understand